# Reuse of temporary in constructor initialisations

Tags: c++, constructor, temporary

When initialising members of a class in its constructor, how can you use the same temporary at more than one point?

Example:

```
// for arbitrary T1, T2, T3
T2 foo(T1 const&);
T3 bar(T1 const&);

struct A {
  T2 const t2;
  T3 const t3;
  A() : t2(foo(T1())), t3(bar(T1())) {}
};
```

This is a very simplified example, but both `t2` and `t3` are constructed depending on an instance of `T1`. Now If I want that object to be precisely the same in both initialisations* I have a problem, because it has no name. Do you have an idea how to solve this without the C++11 *constructor-calls-constructor* feature *nor* adding a dummy class that calls `A(T1())`?

---

*like so:

```
  A(T1 const& t1) : t2(foo(t1)), t3(bar(t1)) {}
```

---

Motivation: What if `T1()` is actually something like `new T()`, where the address of the object matters, such that I have to talk about the same object in both `t2` and `t3`.

Comment: Is that really needed?  Because usually creating a temporary like that takes almost no time at all.

Comment: @MooingDuck: how do you know? Perhaps the constructor of T1 goes off to crawl the interwebs first...

Comment: @bitmask: can't you just let T2 expose _it's_ T1 to T3/A _privately_ (among _[friends](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html))? Like `t2(foo(T1())), t3(bar(t2.getT1()))`

Comment: @MooingDuck: As I said in the *Motivation*, it's actually a `new T(x,y,z)` call instead of an automatic temporary (the pointer is still a temporary, but the actual object is allocated on the heap). And no, unfortunately, I cannot make `A` a composition.

Comment: @sehe: I thought about that, and this is my hack right now, but it's not really a solution I would like to live with. Especially as this constructor will be called precisely one in the program execution.

Comment: @bitmask: away from the question: I think we've hit on at least 2 snags now that were _essential_ additions to the question. It would really be a lot nicer to the SO crowd if you would try to incorporate more of that into the question the first time round (avoids people wasting time). This is commonly referred to as 'tell us what you have already tried, and why it didn't work out'. _In a way, I liked the question because it was so concise, but that was deceptive_. My $0.02

Comment: @sehe: Yes, I feel precisely the same way and I apologise for that. It was my intention to leave out stuff that would've wasted people's time (to read it). As I said in another comment; I overdid. That said, I believe that the solutions that (can) result from what I left out in the original question are mostly hacks and probably too specific to my situation (I believe questions and their answers should be a contribution for the (SO-)community, not only solve one particular hitch of one particular person).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dirty way to reuse a temporary in the constructor initialization is to add a dummy parameter. I'm not keen on this technique, but is the only one I know to give the temporary a name. I tend to redesign my classes to avoid this.

```
struct A
{
    A( T1 temporary_ = T1() )
      : t2( foo( temporary_ ) )
      , t3( bar( temporary_ ) )

    T2 const t2;
    T3 const t3;
};
```

Comment: Well, I can honestly say that I would've never thought of that. And if somebody really wants to pass me a `T1()` it wouldn't really hurt, I guess.

Comment: @bitmask: That's the main problem with it, that it changes the interface the user sees. If it doesn't hurt your design, then its just an acceptable side-effect.

Comment: I don't really like default function parameters in public headers (too many issues with versioning+recompiling+ODR, overrides and overloads IMHO), but it sure starts to look like one of the realistic options, given all the extra _ifs and buts_ the OP has added... +1

Comment: @sehe: Indeed. I would love to hear about an alternative technique. Most of the time I end up designing inner classes to hold both members and provide appropiate construction.

Answer (score 3):

Const-references may be defaulted to a temporary, as of recently (I forget whether that's a C++03 or C++11 addition):

```
A::A(const T & t = T()) : a(t), b(t) { }
//              ^^^^^^
```

(Maybe declare that constructor `explicit`, just in case.)

Comment: @K-ballo: I might actually be confusing this with default template arguments for function templates, coming to think of it. Oh well. Maybe someone can clarify to which standard this conforms.

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this by creating a factory method

```
// for arbitrary T1, T2, T3
T2 foo(T1 const&);
T3 bar(T1 const&);

struct A {
    T2 const t2;
    T3 const t3;
    static A createA() { return A(T1()); }

  private:
     A(const T1& t) : t2(foo(t)), t3(bar(t)) {}
};
```

Comment: I'm in the middle of a deep and complex class hierarchy with non-trivial constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid this situation at all costs, but if I *had* to, I'd add an extra member:

```
struct A {
  T1 temp_;
  T2 const t2;
  T3 const t3;
  A() : temp_(), t2(foo(temp_)), t3(bar(temp_)) {}
};
```

Comment: That's really the perversion of it, as a matter of fact I already have such a member, but I need to pass the temporary to my parent class, which I have to initialise first (I tried to make the question as abstract and simplified as possible, but it appears I cut out too much; **sorry** for that!).

Comment: Then I'd go with storing the value in the parent class, and referencing it subsequently via the base type: `A() : base(T1()), t2(foo(base::m_t1)), t3(bar(base::m_t1)) {}`. But, realize that you may have a problem with the lifetime of the temporary if `base::base(...)` takes the address of the temporary.

Comment: @bitmask -- Oh, I see from your other comments that you actually don't need the same temporary object, you only need the same value. Ignore my comment about lifetime.

Comment: @bitmask: `but I need to pass the temporary to my parent class` - mmm I'm starting to feel your codebase has big design problems. Surely, one class hierarchy cannot suffer from all the design ailments at the same time? Conversely, if all that complexity is required, then the cost is also in order? Use factory patterns, repository patterns, builder patterns, composite, flyweights, IoC, whatever exists. Yes it will cost, but such is life.

Comment: @sehe: I understand that it looks like that, and there are some parts nobody is particularly proud of, but I think this point has a quite logical design. And to your complexity point: factories, templates, dynamic binding, flyweights and to some extent IoC are in place for just the construction this constructor is involved in (one of the reasons btw. I left out information).

Comment: @bitmask: "I need to pass the temporary to my parent class" - pouring even more hacks on top, you could privately inherit from T1 instead of having it as a member. As long as it appears in your list of base classes before the base class you need to pass it to, it'll be available. But I don't like either that or the T1 member, because either changes the lifetime of the "temporary" object.